# How to overriding the maven's url when running gradle

Tags: maven, jenkins, gradle

I have a maven setting in build.gradle like following. You can see I am using a nexus server for internal package management.

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://192.168.0.2:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/'
    }
}
```

Firstly, I cannot build this project in a cloud environment, because this nexus server is not in the cloud.
Secondly, this nexus server could be visited from cloud with a domain name.
Thirdly, I cannot change this url to the domain name because building job is running by Jenkins.

So I am wondering the gradle could support overriding this url value in command line like using -P? Or maybe I can run another gradle task for doing the replace job?

Comment: I have maven installation in the jenkins server, and the mirrors config in settings.xml in ~/.m2 is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the ip of your nexus and have access to your building server I would recommend that you modify the etc/hosts file instead by adding the line:

192.168.0.2  name.of.nexus.host

If you can't solve it this way you can pass a command line value with -P.

```
gradle someTask -PcommandLineProjectProp=commandLineProjectPropValue
```

which gives you the commandLineProjectPropValue to work with in your build.

to use this in your url string you have to use double qoutes("") and $commandLineProjectPropValue.

So:

```
url "$(commandLineProjectPropValue)rest/of/path"
```

Comment: Using the variables for replacing the url is not suitable for my scenario. Because I cannot change the codes for doing this.

Comment: It can't be changed without altering the script.